# Why is Python showing an apostrophe before the numerals in my strings?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to create a directory entry for a family based on data from a Google Spreadsheet. One of the functions is to list any children in a family, along with their birthdays. However, the program is printing an apostrophe before the birthdays for no apparent reason, e.g. '01/01/01 and I can't figure out why. I have converted the data for the birthday to a string, and my other strings are not doing this. Why is this happening?

Here are the relevant portions of the sourcecode:

```
    import gspread
    gc =gspread.login('mylogin','password')
    spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key("mykey")
    worksheet = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)
    Child1=(worksheet.cell(x,13)).value
    Child1BD=(worksheet.cell(x,14)).value
    Child2=(worksheet.cell(x,15)).value
    Child2BD=(worksheet.cell(x,16)).value
    Child3=(worksheet.cell(x,17)).value
    Child3BD=(worksheet.cell(x,18)).value
    Child4=(worksheet.cell(x,19)).value
    Child4BD=(worksheet.cell(x,20)).value
    # If there are no children, return without doing anything.
    if Child1 == "n/a":
        return;
    # If there is one child only, print the child's name and birthday.
    elif Child2 == "n/a" and Child1 != "n/a":
        print str(Child1)+"- "+str(Child1BD)
        return;
    # If thre are exactly two children, print their names and birthdays.
    elif Child3 == "n/a" and Child2 != "n/a":
        print str(Child1)+"- "+str(Child1BD)
        print str(Child2) +"- "+str(Child2BD)
        return;
    # If there are exactly three children, print their names and birthdays.
    elif Child4 == "n/a" and Child3 != "n/a":
        print str(Child1)+"- "+str(Child1BD)
        print str(Child2) +"- "+str(Child2BD)
        print str(Child3) +"- "+str(Child3BD)
        return;
    # If there are four children, print their names and birthdays.
    elif Child4 != "n/a":
        print str(Child1)+"- "+str(Child1BD)
        print str(Child2) +"- "+str(Child2BD)
        print str(Child3) +"- "+str(Child3BD)
        print str(Child4) +"- "+str(Child4BD)
        return;
```

Comment: What does `print repr(Child1)` print out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the way Excel stores string internally. You'll have to remove it before you print it.

The apostrophe indicates that it's a string and not a number.

Comment: *certain* strings. (And this isn't Excel, it's Google Spreadsheet)

Comment: @nneonneo, thanks I missed that. I assume Google works the same as Excel so it can be compatible with Excel files.

Comment: And the solution is [`str(Child1BD).lstrip("'")`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: @Robᵩ, careful, you probably really only want to strip one. The string "'''Foo" would display "''Foo". `s=s[s[0]=="'":]`

Comment: @gnibbler clever use of the boolean to int conversion.

Comment: Yes, mine is flawed for the reason @gnibbler said.

Answer (score 1):

The `'` is used in excel to prevent it from trying to guess the formatting for the cell.
For example if you want to prevent cells automatically converting to dates, you enter a `'` before the `01/01/2013`

If you don't know where a string is coming from it's a good idea to prepend a `'` to prevent this magical (possibly confusing) reformatting

As Mark says, it's probably the same in Google Spreadsheet to remain compatible

In general it should be safe to strip the `'` off to get the displayed string, just be careful about putting the unescaped string back into the spreadsheet